# Isabelle failed to finish proof even though this is same as goal

Tags: isabelle

My code is as follows. I expected it to work perfectly, and indeed by the end of the final "hence" line (which was found by Sledgehammer), Isabelle claims that `this` is `∀y. ∃x. P x y`, and that its goal has one subgoal only which is `∀y. ∃x. P x y`. These two expressions are identical, so I would have thought Isabelle would accept the proof as finished.

```
lemma assumes "EX x. ALL y. P x y" shows "ALL y. EX x. P x y"
proof -
 fix y
 assume "EX x. ALL f. P x f"
 then obtain x where "ALL f. P x f" by blast
 hence "P x y" by blast
 hence "ALL y. EX x. P x y" using `∀f. P x f` by blast
qed
```

What have I missed? I'm a beginner in Isabelle, as is probably evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands `have` and `hence` only state intermediate facts that you wish to prove. You have to say explicitly that a statement is supposed to discharge a goal. To do that, you have to use `show` or `thus` instead of `have` or `hence`. So if you replace your last `hence` with `thus`, the proof should succeed (modulo the remarks below). You can also see in the `Output` buffer (or by hovering with the mouse over `thus` that you get a message saying `Successful attempt to solve goal by exported rule ...`. This indicates that the goal was really discharged.

By the way, the proof will not work as expected. First, in the initial step where you write `proof -`, you actually want to do introduction for the universal quantifier (as you fix the `y` in the next step. Therefore, the `-` should be replaced with the appropriate rule application, namely `(rule allI)`. Consequently, your show statement should then be `EX x. P x y` rather than `ALL y. EX x. P x y`.

Second, the `assumes` in the lemma statement already adds the assumption to the context. Therefore, there is no need to assume it once more inside the proof. In fact, Isabelle will complain at `show` or `thus` that it is unable to solve the goal. So you should delete the `assume ...` part and replace it with a reference to the assumption, e.g., using the predefined name `assms`.